# Boost sound volume on my MXQ Android box where Audio Boost apps don't work

Tags: audio, device-firmware, android-tv, volume, build.prop

This is MXQ Pro 4k box on Amlogic S905 chip.

It is embarrassingly quiet when playing through the AV jack with some good active speakers attached. My Ubuntu laptop is able to play loud on those speakers. The MXQ Box itself is able to play loud via the HDMI when connected to a regular TV.

I suspect Android thinks it's headphones attached to the AV jack and halves the volume to save my ears. But actually it's good speakers and I want it loud.

Volume boost programs don't work. One of them - "Volume Booster GOODEV" - splashed a baloon saying something like "Loudness Enhancer Effect" is unavailable to the app.

So I went redeye and started exploring the files on the device.

`/system/etc/audio_effects.conf` mentions the loudness enhancer twice, the `.so` file is in place at the path mentioned, looks ok to my ignorant view:

```
libraries: {
......
  loudness_enhancer {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libldnhncr.so
  }
}
.....
effects: {
  loudness_enhancer {
    library loudness_enhancer
    uuid fa415329-2034-4bea-b5dc-5b381c8d1e2c
  }
}
```

So I thought I am unable to give the Goodev app and plethora of other equalizers access to the effects, and started to dig more.

I somehow managed to add "volume steps" in the `build.prop`:

```
ro.config.media_vol_steps=16
```

unfortunately that didn't make the speakers any louder.

Is there a `ro.config.media_vol_max_db` anywhere? How do people know what magic letters to spell in the config?...

Okay, then I've googled about the `mixer_paths.xml` that allows people to boost the voulmes of their phones from some default 84 mystery units to 100... unfortunately, this is how my `mixer_paths.xml` file looks like:

```
<mixer>
  <!-- dummy xml conf, do nothing here -->
  <path name="speaker">
  </path>

  <path name="headphone">
  </path>

  <path name="main_mic">
  </path>

  <path name="headset-mic">
  </path>
</mixer>
```

Question: **what should I try next?**

The firmware looks a little like this if you want to really dig in

https://mega.nz/file/l1x0GLDY#p3hs8aZxIAMM5LwIOtfpyis_w7C7XPQgYYBevGxkAmc

the board looks like this

https://ds-blobs-3.cdn.devapps.ru/8413380.jpg

**Add:** There are some ALSA artifacts in the filesystem, too: `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and `../pcm/default.conf`

Comment: I haven't ever fiddled with an android box, so this may be a stupid suggestion - obviously device is rooted (seeing what you tried), so why not install ViPER4Android (V4a) on it? // Be warned that V4a installation on a normal Android phone can vary from being easy to make you pull your hair out//Google XDA and other sources for the appropriate V4a for the Android version running on the box and you can tweak not only loudness, bass etc but it is only limited by the skill you have and your taste

Comment: @beeshyams, I'm trying but I'm having difficulties even finding an appropriate apk to download (nothing in Google Play, many links are dead or kinda sus)

Comment: What is the Android version? Check on the Telegram group here (I downloaded from here for Android 12 but it may work for you too but better to ask in the group) https://t.me/ViPER4AndroidFX

Comment: it's 5.1.1, the cpu can't bear any newer. it was collecting dust on the shelf because I gave up a couple of years ago to boost the volume... Will try the link (doesn't download from the web telegram for some reason)

Comment: I've seen this link but it doesn't work for me - server doesn't ping: Name or service not known. Tor tried too to no avail. Another link mentioned in the thread - https://zackptg5.com/android.php#viper - has some "magisk" zip which I only have to figure out what to do with. Thank you a lot for helping! I think I will eventually manage to try it. However there they say that you have to switch off some MusicFX - I do have one, and their functions seem duplicating. so I'm wondering if I'm able to increase the volume with some existing tool also

Comment: This may help https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-make-viper4android-work-on-5-0-x-lollipop.3018961/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131195/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-fedd).

Comment: I already feel uncomfortable to borrow so much of your time for this, especially with me not really wanting to become an android hacker for just wanting to increase the volume of some chinese box. But if I dive into it (I already see the requirement to switch off the MusicFX and everything) I will ask you for some minor details in chat, *thank you*!